# VBA - Connect 2 If Conditions & 2 Message Boxes

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have written the following code:

```
  Dim myValue As Variant
    Dim myValue2 As Variant
    Dim myValue3 As Variant
    Dim myValue4 As Variant
    On Error GoTo ErrorOccured
    If Target.Address = "$B$10" And Target.Value = "Yes" Then
        myValue = InputBox("Insert initialDate1")
        myValue2 = InputBox("Insert initialDate2")
        Range("C10").Value = myValue
        Range("D10").Value = myValue2
        End If


   If Target.Address = "$B$12" And Target.Value = "Yes" Then
        myValue3 = InputBox("InitialDate3")
        myValue4 = InputBox("InitialDate4")
        Range("C12").Value = myValue3
        Range("D12").Value = myValue4
        End If
ErrorOccured:
    'Do when value is not valid
    End Sub
```

Its purpose is the following:
if I select Yes from a drop down list, the code must ask me to fill a beginning and ending date of the first event and then
it should go to the second event, again select yes from a drop down list and ask for beginning and and dates. My problem is that I don't know how to connect these two conditions so that they stay independent. I cannot use And Or, Else or the other classic connectors. I should be able to select Yes for the first Event and input the dates and for ex select No for the second event end no pop up appears. It worked when I wrote the code for only one Event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myValue As Variant
    Dim myValue2 As Variant
    On Error GoTo ErrorOccured
    If Target.Address = "$B$10" And Target.Value = "Yes" Then
        myValue = InputBox("Insert initialDate1")
        myValue2 = InputBox("Insert initialDate2")
        Range("C10").Value = myValue
        Range("D10").Value = myValue2
         End If
ErrorOccured:
 End Sub
```

Please, could you help me with this one?

Comment: So you want the second IF execute only if the first one executed?

Comment: Hi, Foxfire And Burns And Burns. No, I want for the second if to execute independent of the first If but to keep both conditions (if possible) in the same code. Truth be told, I do not know how to separate two IFs, when working in the Private Sub mode. Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you use your code as shown?

Comment: but your code does that now. What happends if you execute that code now? also, remove the `On Error GoTo ErrorOccured` to see if any error arises

Comment: You know what,  Foxfire And Burns And Burns? It works!!! :-) Thank you for the error suggestion and for replying.